# What happens at the boundary of the Brillouin Zone?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, crystals, braggs-law

I believe that at the boundary of Brilluoin Zone i.e, at -π/a,π/a. Taking k=π/a we have k=2π/λ
so λ=2a. Making the group velocity zero. Does it point to Braggs law? What does it really signify?